# select from values in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

What would be the MySQL way for doing a select from values?

```
select c from (values (1), (2), (3)) as t(c);
```

The idea is to be able to do something like this:

```
select * from table, (values (1), (2), (3)) as temp(c) where ...;
```

For reference, here is the Postgres doc:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-values.html

Answer (score 29):

From the link you provided :

> VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three');
>   This will return a table of two columns and three rows. It's effectively equivalent to:
>   SELECT 1 AS column1, 'one' AS column2
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT 2, 'two'
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT 3, 'three';

So you need

```
select * from 
table1,
(
   SELECT 1 AS val
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3 
)b
```

Comment: This is equivalent to my example but seems to be a lot of work as opposed to the Postgres syntax. Does MySQL has such an option?

Comment: It is a bit more work to do since MySQL doesn't have any VALUES syntax. If you have many values that you need to retrieve, you could create a procedure to split your values by a delimiter, insert them in a temporary table and then select them properly. Would that be easier for you?

Comment: Actually I don't want to retrieve these values. I want to do something more complex than "in" so I would need them in a temporary table of some sort

Comment: @cristism: From what Postgres says I conclude its `VALUES` in such case is just a syntax sugar, so no performance penalty for `UNION ALL`... Yeah, `UNION` syntax is more verbose...

Comment: @StelianMatei what would be the syntax for using a temporary table to achieve the same?

Answer (score 12):

In MySQL 8.0.19, this syntax is supported. please refer to this [official link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html)

```
mysql> VALUES ROW(1,-2,3), ROW(5,7,9), ROW(4,6,8);
+----------+----------+----------+
| column_0 | column_1 | column_2 |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |       -2 |        3 |
|        5 |        7 |        9 |
|        4 |        6 |        8 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: And in MariaDB 10.3, it's `VALUES (1,-2,3), (5,7,9), (4,6,8);`

Answer (score 9):

This is another way to get around the lack of `WITH` support in `MySQL`:

```
create temporary table tmp (c int);

insert into tmp (c)
values (1), (2), (3);

select * from tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is so sad.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, found this Q, eventually fiddled around to get this:

```
select c
from (values row(1)
           , row(2)
           , row(3)
     ) t(c)
;
```

So for the OP's second part:

```
select *
from table
   , (values row(1)
           , row(2)
           , row(3)
     ) t(c)
where ...
;
```